# CSS file not linking in Eclipse

Tags: html, css, eclipse

I have a simple HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> Resources Test </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1> This is a HTML resource. </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And a CSS file

```
h1{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Both the HTML file and the CSS files are in the same folder.

[image]

Still while opening localhost, I do not get any CSS editing.

[image]

I tried using `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/demo.css">` but even that did not work

Comment: isn't the href wrong. I think it should be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css">` or,

```css
h1{
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> Resources Test </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1> This is a HTML resource. </h1>
</body>
</html>
<!--the href doesn't matter here since this is auto sourced to the css, but in your project it will-->
```

, I don't think you need to specify the type on external stylesheets. If this doesn't work, maybe try to set a background color on your body to test, it could be the code. If *that* doesn't work, another way is putting the CSS directly into your HTML file, by putting a `<style>` tag in your header, and putting your CSS in there. Lastly, try to put the exact location of you file in your desktop, with a file:/// before it, you can do this on windows by going to your file in file explorer, right-clicking, tap properties, and tap general, then check *location*, and copy that into your link stylesheet href.